# How can I transfer my old mouse scroll speed to a new mouse?

Tags: windows-7, logitech-mouse

I recently replaced my old mouse and keyboard with Logitech hardware, both connected via unifying receiver. But the movement speed of my old (wired Logitech mouse) differs from my new mouse.

How can I find out how fast my old mouse was to set my new mouse to the same speed?

I use Windows 7 x64 Professional.

Answer (score 2):

Just as [Tetsujin wrote](https://superuser.com/a/802595/194694), mouse resolution is measured in DPI, but real DPI sometimes doesn't match advertised values. Perfect measurement is hard or even impossible, but there's a program that can give you quite good approximation (±25 dpi error when used correctly). It's called VMouseBench and it's in Polish, but using it is quite easy.

1. Click the third tab (*Rozdzielczość*).
2. Click anywhere.
3. Move your mouse 0.5" away very slowly and without sudden moves.
4. Click again.

Measured DPI will appear at the bottom (*Zmierzone DPI*). Make sure you don't move the pointer out of program's window because measurement won't be successful. If the pointer moves too fast switch to 0.25" at the bottom.

Why measuring DPI yourself is better than trusting manufacturer?

- I've seen a mouse that was 600 dpi advertised and 350 dpi in reality
- I've also seen a mouse that was 1000 dpi advertised and 1100 dpi in reality

Answer (score 1):

Mouse tracking is measured in DPI [dots per inch] so the accurate way to do it would be to discover the DPI of the old mouse & see if your new mouse has a variable DPI setting to match it.

Alternatively, you could just wing it & go to either the regular Windows Control Panel for Mouse or the specific Logitech one & set the Pointer or Tracking speed by trial & error, til it feels right.